# std::setfill and std::setw for input streams?

Tags: c++, parsing, integer, istream, setw

Consider this code:

```
int xx;
std::cin >> std::setfill('0') >> std::setw(4) >> xx;
```

When sending `12` to the standard input I am expecting the value of `xx` to be `1200` and when sending `12345` I am expecting it to be `1234`.

However, it seems `std::setfill` and `std::setw` have no effect and I am getting `12` and `12345` respectively.

Is this a bug or it is according to the standard? Is there a good way to get the expected functionality?

Also note, when I change the type of `xx` to be `std::string` the `std::setw` takes effect while `std::setfill` still doesn't.

My compiler is `gcc-7.0.1`.

Comment: Maybe I missed it. Since when is `std::setfill` supported on *input* stream operations? I know `std::setw` is, but now `std::setfill` is too ???

Comment: nope, it's malformed code.

Comment: I don't think `std::setfill` supported on input stream. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill

Comment: xx will receive whatever value you inputted. You need to show what you do with it afterwards, and that can be formatted

Comment: The fact that the above code compiles kind of legalizes the motivation to have the desired functionality.

Answer (score 3):

According to C++ standard, `setfill` pertains to **output** stream. As for the `setw`, it works for input stream when used together with `char*` or `string`. For example, following program outputs `abcd` for input string `abcdef` (and `1234` for `123456`):

```
string a;
cin >> setw(4) >> a;
cout << a;
```

Answer (score 1):

`setw` and `setfill` are not applied so universally.

It sounds like you want to imitate the effect of formatting the given input in a fixed-width column, then re-reading it. The library does provide tools for exactly that:

```
int widen_as_field( int in, int width, char fill ) {
    std::stringstream field;
    field << std::setw( width ) << std::setfill( fill );
    field << std::setiosflags( std::ios::left );
    field << in;
    int ret;
    field >> ret;
    return ret;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/defd48debc270f83).

This function will not trim `12345` to `1234`, though. That would take another conversion through `string`.

Comment: This is insanely inefficient because it converts digits to int twice.

Answer (score 1):

Due to historical accident, GCC and MSVC support using `setfill` with an istream. It will call `ios::fill(c)` to store the fill character, but that is never used by any of the extraction functions that read values from an istream. So you can compile it, but it doesn't do what the OP expects.

In the olden times, most I/O manipulators worked with both input and output streams. In mid-1996 (i.e. prior to the original C++98 standard) the specification for I/O manipulators was changed by issue 27-652 in [N0958](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1996/N0958.pdf) and  issue 27-651 in [N0964](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1996/N0964.pdf).

It seems that the iostreams implementations in GCC and MSVC were never adjusted for the change that made `setfill` only apply to ostreams. The Clang library (libc++) was written from scratch around 2010 and so was implemented according to the final standard, without any remnants of draft standards from the 1990s.

Interestingly, (at least some editions of) the book *Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales: Advanced Programmer's Guide and Reference* by Angelika Langer and Klaus Kreft also said that `setfill` worked with both input and output streams. So it wasn't only GCC and Dinkumware that didn't get the memo about the change.

Comment: A very interesting tidbit from the seemingly boundless annals of C++ antiquity.